# In Intellij, the 'Select Run/Debug Configuration' is hiding due to large default test name, also hiding other icons after it

Tags: intellij-idea, scalatest

Each time I right click and run a test, the intellij, picks a large test name for the 'test-run' and hence, hiding the 'Select Run/Debug Configuration' icon and all those which come after it. What can i do to collapse the test name, so that everything is visible to me again?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?
I have not seen a problem like this and I am not sure if I understand it.

Comment: Just learn the keyboard shortcuts. The gui is for wimps...